# React properties/function assignment/declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to `React`, but not to `JS`.
Here's a piece of code, that I couldn't understand

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShowCard from './ShowCard';
import Header from './Header';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: ''
  };
  props: {
    shows: Array<Show>
  };
  handleSearchTermChange = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent & {target: HTMLInputElement}) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search"></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Within the class there are expressions like `state = ...` and `props: {..`.
Also function definitions like `render(){}` and `handleSearchTermChange = (...`.
As I recall from all these valid ES6 one is `render`. How does it work? If I switch the way data assigned to `state/props` - everything brakes. I assume it's some kind of `babel` plugin, is it?

Comment: This is JavaScript with [**Flow**](https://flow.org/). [**This**](https://pastebin.com/bKTq5TXQ) would be the equivalent in just JavaScript, without [**PropTypes**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.

The react docs usually defines state via the `constructor() {}` object. However, in certain projects, we can simply do so via `state = {}`. This shorthand syntax is possible due to a Babel transpiler called [Class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).